# Is it possible to create password protected drives in on shared network storage (NAS) on windows?

Tags: windows, networking, raid, nas

Goal:

To have Raid 10 on NAS for home office.

It will have files that users share with each other, under public folder, and files that are private to each user but stored for backup reasons on the NAS.

User should be able to set a folder to back up Or manually go to the network drive as you'd go to C: drive.

But only user can go to drive they have password to, and they'd have to enter password once and they'd stay connected to it. Other users shouldn't be able to browse other users, maybe admin.

I've never done this, so please dont use Abbreviations a lot.

Answer (score 1):

What protocol are you using to share the remote filesystem? SMB, which is what windows uses, supports user authentication so you can setup different shares for each user with different passwords and each share would point to the respective user's directory. I think SMB also has the concept of home directories so you may be able to create one share and setup a different home directory for each user.